# SQL query - Count of union of select

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, union

sorry to disturb you but I got a problem with a count of union; I try to implement the same logic that I read in other post but it's not working for me, some help please?

This is my code:
/*Declaration of data*?

```
/*where i should make the count*/

/*first select*/

UNION

/*second select*/
/*in the where of the second select I have a case with the following data*/
 CASE
    WHEN ((@case='other') AND (cfv.value like '%,' + cast (@today as VARCHAR) or cfv.value like '%' + cast    (@today as VARCHAR) 
    or cfv.value like '%' + cast (@today as VARCHAR)+',0'
    or cfv.value like '%' + cast (@today as VARCHAR)+',0,1'
    or cfv.value like '%' + cast (@today as VARCHAR)+',1'))
    then 1
    WHEN ((@case ='zero') AND(cfv.value='0')) THEN 1
    WHEN ((@case ='one') AND(cfv.value='1' or cfv.value='0,1')) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END = 1
```

and this re result without count so I suppose that should be very easy but I don't get it :S
[Just a column of elements but I'd like to have the number of the element present in this case 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qv52z.jpg)

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: Too much code and not enough explanation of what the problem is and what your expected output should be. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a case statement in your where should not mess up the syntax. It is probably something else.

Make sure when doing a subquery you give it an alias.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    /*first select*/
    UNION
    /*second select*/
    WHERE
    CASE
      WHEN ((@case='other') 
            AND (cfv.value LIKE '%,' + CAST(@today AS VARCHAR)
                 OR cfv.value LIKE '%' + CAST(@today AS VARCHAR) 
                 OR cfv.value LIKE '%' + CAST(@today AS VARCHAR)+',0'
                 OR cfv.value LIKE '%' + CAST(@today AS VARCHAR)+',0,1'
                 OR cfv.value LIKE '%' + CAST(@today AS VARCHAR)+',1'))
      THEN 1
      WHEN ((@case ='zero') AND (cfv.value='0')) THEN 1
      WHEN ((@case ='one') AND  (cfv.value='1' OR cfv.value='0,1')) THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END = 1
) AS alias --<<--
```

Comment: i'll try and let you know ;) tkssss

Comment: nop, but I solver in another way, I don't remember how I did but if you want I'll post the solution asap

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get a count of all the records selected, you could do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
    SELECT First...
    UNION
    SELECT Second...
) AS CountTable
```

Just wrap your whole query in another `SELECT` statement and count from there.

Comment: I'm trying to do that but seeing that the last element it's a case it give me an error :S

Comment: The CASE statement shouldn't cause a problem.  Does the query run properly without the `SELECT COUNT(*)` wrapper and give you the list of IDs?

Comment: yes, is giving me an exception just when i put the count (*)

Comment: What is the error you're getting?  Update your question with the new query and the error text so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Just fixed it - the last line of my answer didn't paste in properly the first time.  It needs the `AS AliasName` at the end, like fqhv has in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping it in a select.

```
SELECT t.CompanyID, COUNT(*)
FROM (YOUR UNION QUERY) t
GROUP BY t.CompanyID
```

Comment: same problem, it give me an error when I close the parenthesis near of the END=1 of the case of the second select :S

Comment: Does the query run fine without adding the COUNT()?

Comment: yes it does :S and give me the results that I showed in my first post :S